# Breaking dynamic text line in Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text, newline

I am using data driven pages and some of my dynamic text attributes are too long for my layout.

Is there a way to break the line into 2 or more lines with out editing the data?

Example:

**FROM**

Billy Joes Dry Cleaners LLC

**TO**

Billy Joes
Dry Cleaners LLC

Answer (score 8):

It may be that what you are looking for is to be able to flow/wrap text within rectangular text elements.

How to do this is documented in the help page on  [Adding text that flows within a graphic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000004000000).

Answer (score 6):

Came across this looking for the same answer.

The best way I found is to add a \n, in the attribute text, where you want your break.

Billy Joes \n Dry Cleaners LLC

=

Billy Joes

Dry Cleaners LLC

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to insert a line break into the data.

1. When editing place the cursor at the point you want to cause the
   break and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will place a hard break in the
   data.
2. If you have maplex extension you might get the labelstacker option
   to work.

[image: Labelstacker]

You will need to be creative with the label different classes or ALL of your labels will do the same thing.
I set up different queries to label some items with breaks and others without.

Comment: @Acrain If you are using ArcGIS 10.1 then Maplex will be available to you at any license level - see [**here**](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maplex/).

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the overflowing dynamic text line, open its properties, copy the text out of it, and paste it into a new text box that fits your layout the way you want. Or you can start from scratch and create the data-driven text the way you want it. The various dynamic text elements (page number, document title, etc.) are all just tags that can be inserted in any text on your layout. There's a full list of them in the online [ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000).